# Tense of verb after as though

Tags: tense, past-perfect

> 1. Andy acts as though he knew everything

> 2. Andy acted as though he knew everything

> 3. Andy acted as though he had known everything

I know that the first sentence is correct. But what about the next two? Should I use *past perfect tense* in the clause following 'as though' if the clause before it is in *past indefinite*?

Comment: I would expect (1) to read '...as though he knows everything'. (2) is fine.  (3) seems to me to need something more, such as '...as though he had known everything about it for a long time.'

Comment: I thought 'as though' and 'as if' could be used to mean improbable situations, e.g.  when someone acts like they know everything but in reality they do not. I thought in these situations 'as though' and 'as if' were followed by past form of verbs as in (1).

Comment: They _are_ used for hypothetical situations - obviously no-one can 'know everything'. However, they don't have to be followed by the past tense. See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-though (scroll down to the examples).